# How to print all properties, values of an Object and its all childrens recursively?

Tags: java

I have tried the following apis without success

```
BeanUtils.describe(dialog)
ReflectionToStringBuilder
System.out.println(new XStream(
                      new Sun14ReflectionProvider(
                          new FieldDictionary(
                            new ImmutableFieldKeySorter())),   
                         new DomDriver("utf-8")
                     ).toXML(object)
                  ) - Out of memory exception.
```

I am debugging the object in IntelliJ and it is very time consuming and huge properties and hashmap and hashset are being inside the child object and as well as in the nested object.

Basically i want to print all the properties, values of all the objects of the given object.

Please help me.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Do you have any control over this object? Also, do you know what types the sub-objects are? Do they override `toString()`? If so, you may not have to use reflection at all...

Comment: Likely your object has circular references or actually big. Perhaps "raw" reflection API is more appropriate in your case because thus you can control how deeply you need to dive in

Comment: I have a string value but not sure from which property or value or variable of an object it has been popped up. i want to print whole objects to see where the string actually present...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). It serializes every thing in the object that can be serializable. You'll have to be careful about the cyclic dependences though. Jackson doesn’t like them. use `@JsonIgnore` when required Combine the JSON output with [JSON Editor](http://jsoneditoronline.org) and you'll have a very nice representation of your object.

I am not sure why you need this though. IntelliJ IDE should be able to give you a good representation of your object during debug time

Comment: I have a string value but not sure from which property or value or variable of an object it has been popped up. i want to print whole objects to see where the string actually present...